# Unable to write audio queue to file to m4a

Tags: swift, avfoundation, audiotoolbox

I currently use AVAudioRecorder to record audio in an app. If the app crashes or something happens while recording, the file being recorded is lost so as an alternative, I'm trying to use Audio Queue Services to record and write to a file.

I have it working perfectly using LinearPCM but cannot get it to work with m4a encoding. I'm trying to replicate the file format that AVRecorder uses.The file gets written but can't be opened. I think it has to do with my settings but I can't be sure.

The settings I'm using in the AVAudioRecorder are;

```
        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 16000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ]
```

This is what works with the Audio Queue Service;

```
        var recordingFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
        memset(&recordingFormat, 0, MemoryLayout<AudioStreamBasicDescription>.size)
    
        recordingFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
        recordingFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1
        recordingFormat.mSampleRate = 16000
        recordingFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16
        recordingFormat.mBytesPerFrame = UInt32(1*MemoryLayout<Int16>.stride)
        recordingFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1
        recordingFormat.mBytesPerPacket = UInt32(1*MemoryLayout<Int16>.stride)
        recordingFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked
        var propSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioStreamBasicDescription>.size)
```

and then writing to file using;

```
CheckError(AudioFileCreateWithURL(audioOutputFileName as CFURL,
                                          kAudioFileCAFType,
                                              &recordingFormat,
                                              AudioFileFlags.eraseFile,
                                              &self.outFile), "Write to file failed")
```

For M4A, I've tried a bunch of combinations and again, the file gets written out but can't be opened

Here is one example that I thought woudl work but doesn't

```
        recordingFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC
        recordingFormat.mSampleRate = 44100
        recordingFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1
        recordingFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 0
        recordingFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 0
        recordingFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 0
        recordingFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1024
```

and to write out the file;

```
        CheckError(AudioFileCreateWithURL(audioOutputFileName as CFURL,
                                          kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
                                              &recordingFormat,
                                              AudioFileFlags.eraseFile,
                                              &self.outFile), "Write to file failed")
```

These settings actually crash the app. I've tried using various AudioFileTypeID values. Some crash and others will write the file but can't be opened.

Answer (score 0):

`kAudioFileCAFType` is not an `M4A` file, create it using `kAudioFileM4AType` instead. Make sure to call `AudioFileClose()` too, as that should write out the header.

Comment: yes you’re right.  But when I set the queue format to mpeg4aac, the queue fails to create for a reason I don’t know which is what I’m trying to find out. The queue settings for setting it up for mpeg4aac.

Comment: All that stuff sounds like it should work. Can you share some runnable code?

Comment: So it ends up my issue was the enum values for the AudioFileCreateWithURL contains kAudioFile... and kAudioFormat... and I was using kAudioFormat instead of File. I changed to mpeg4 and that allowed the file to write but after all that, I guess m4a files need to be explicitly closed or they can't be opened? I switched to audio queue services to be able to recover in case of interrruption or crash and I can recover the caf files but not the m4a. The caf files are readable any time but not m4a so looks like I'll just have to convert them to m4a when recording stops.

Comment: Yes, closing the file writes its header.